# html5up templates adding extra font awesome icons

Tags: html, css, icons

I am trying to make a website based on the free HTML5up template
http://html5up.net/prologue

Anyone know how to get the Deviantart social icon? I tried adding the html code

fa fa-deviantart solo

but when I view it, the link is fine but the icon is in the shape of a can instead of the normal Deviantart icon. Please help? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you have added the Font Awesome css inside your head tag or not.

With out that you can't get the icon you are looking for.
[click here to download font awesome file](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/). Or add this inside the head tag.

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

below is the sample to add icons from font awesome collections.

```
<i class="fa fa-deviantart"></i> fa-deviantart
```

Please check this [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) for more info.

Comment: ps YEAH it works now (ignore my comment above).
For some strange reason it wasn't picking up the link you gave me, I had to put http: in front of it.
Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `fa-deviantart` is new in FontAwesome 4.1, and does not seem to be available in the template you're using. Try adding this line to your `<head>` tag:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

That should make the latest FA library available, and `fa-deviantart` worked when I tested it.

[image: fa-deviantart icon]

Comment: I tried all that, but now nothing at all is showing just a space.

Comment: I tried all that, but now nothing at all is showing - just a space. I have looked at their style.css and it seems they have embedded the font awesome into that rather than a link to the fontawesome min.css They have also added styles like fa fa solo and so the i class doesn't work. You said you got the deviantart icon, so I dont know.